# can someone tell me how to fix AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk'

Tags: python

i need help finding what the problem is for this.
this is my code.

```
import tkinter
import keyboard


def createwindow():
   

     gui = tkinter.Tk()
        gui.title('Easy Scripts')
        gui.geometry('325x1080+-10+-30')
        gui.attributes('-alpha,.5')
        gui.configure(bg='black')
        gui.mainloop()


while True:
    if keyboard.read_key() == "p":
        createwindow()
```

first the error will say "`AttributeError: module 'keyboard' has no attribute 'read_key'**strong text*`*" then when i delete the keypress part the new error is "`AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk'`" someone please help meenter code here

Comment: Try reinstalling your packages using `pip`. From what it seems you can't access any member of your imported modules. You can use this command `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall <packageName>`

Answer (score 0):

The error means that there is no `tkinter.Tk` (which shouldnt happen, actually. There should be a .Tk).

The reason your error changes when you delete the key press line is because the key press line also caused an error.

Try reinstalling your packages

Comment: i just tried that and now it just saids "AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk''. with the keypress can you tell me how to fix this thx :)

Comment: It seems to be the same issue for both errors, your modules arent imported correctly. What compiler are you using?

Comment: visual studio code python

Comment: the code now lets me run it but when i press the key (g) it brings up this.

Comment: Have you installed the python extension? If not then uhh i dont know now lol

Comment: my extemsions are "exe  runner, jupyter, opencv, pylance, python". i think the reason this could have happened is i deleted like a file that was like __init__

Comment: PS C:\Users\****\OneDrive\Desktop\Scripts> & C:/Users/****/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/****/OneDrive/Desktop/Scripts/test2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users*****\OneDrive\Desktop\Scripts\test2.py", line 16, in <module>
    createwindow()
  File "c:\Users****\OneDrive\Desktop\Scripts\test2.py", line 6, in createwindow
    gui = tkinter.Tk()
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk'

Comment: You deleted some launch.json or like init.json file? I guess that explains a bit
Also you dont need to post the whole error :|

Comment: Try making a new python file, does that work, if not then try reinstalling vscode

Comment: its still having the same problem
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk'